# Implementation JWT on Application (Understanding concept of JWT)

Tags: php, jwt

I just learn JWT on PHP. I'm a litle bit understand how JWT work on single page. When I implementating on multiple page (page to another page).

Is my implementation true if every user move to another page we have to fill HTTP_AUTHORIZATION with token (bearer code) and in the same time we generate new token ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share more details. What do you mean by "single page"? What makes you think that you need to generate a new token at any time?

Comment: It probably depends if you're talking about a browser-based UI or an API. With a UI the initial token probably gets exchanged for a session ID which the browser then uses to identify itself to the server. With an API you usually have to send the token with every request (because there's no concept of Session and therefore it's more stateless).

Comment: @Adyon, if we work on browser-based UI, should I store it on cookie ? then we can accsess it from another page.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, JWT is a bearer token issued to user after successful login using their username and password.

Normally for mobile app we set long expiry for a JWT token, while for a web app, we use the JWT refresh mechanism to avoid invalid API abuse by invalidating the old token and refresh with a new set of token without login again. Once the JWT token is expired, then will need to kick the user out.

For a mobile app, JWT can be saved in SharedPreference and use the same key for all API calls. Set it as an environment instead of page based, so that you no need to set it again every time in every page.

Have a read on this https://tech.justeattakeaway.com/2019/12/04/lessons-learned-from-handling-jwt-on-mobile/

Comment: Is that them same way like we store that token on cookie ?

Comment: For normal website, we use session. Session is not the same as cookie. But for API based website, we need to use a bearer token for authentication.